Minority-carrier only injection into bulk semiconductor
If an n-type bulk semiconductor sample was injected from the side with holes. Such that holes are injected uniformly into a small region near the side surface of the sample. Does this excess minority carrier (holes) stay on the surface only while attracting electrons to it or does it diffuse inside the material only or does it diffuse while still attracting electrons?

In other words, does total current density (Jp+Jn) equation contain drift current only or diffusion only or both?

Minority carriers diffuse just fine. This is pretty critical to operation of various semiconductor devices.

According to Neamen, when he considered this case he stated the current density to be the conductivity×dE/dx which seems to me as neglecting the diffusion term!

Well, it is true that they may not diffuse very far before recombining. That all depends on the actual doping levels. For low doping, one would expect fairly long diffusion lengths. For high doping not so much. Perhaps what is discussed in the book is an initial limiting case.

This answer probably answers your question. freecharly (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/129209/freecharly), Does ambipolar transport when an electric field is applied to the semiconductor imply zero drift current?, URL (version: 2017-02-23): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314132
