Current due to Ambipolar transport of excess carrier in semiconductors
I am reading Neaman's textbook and I am confused by the ambipolar transport phenomenon. According to what I have understood, if excess carriers are injected somehow into a doped semiconductor piece, then these carriers will drift and diffuse together according to the minority carrier coefficients. Doesn't this imply that the current densities due to the excess carriers equal to zero!? I understand that there might be a net current due to the majority carrier drift, but my point is that excess carriers together made their net current zero so that the total current is still only that of the equilibrium majority carrier drift or diffusion!

Positive carriers moving one way and negative carriers moving the other way combine to make a total current equal to the the sum of the two.

But according to the text, excess carriers do not move in opposite ways! They move together either drifting or diffusing.

See my answer to this question here: freecharly (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/129209/freecharly), Does ambipolar transport when an electric field is applied to the semiconductor imply zero drift current?, URL (version: 2017-02-23): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314132

I did already read it even before my question, but what I don't understand is how do those electrons shield a pulse of minority holes but without having current? How do they accumulate without moving if I understand the absence of their current correctly!?

@MarcusHany The majority electrons move, but only very fast to aggregate to shield the minority holes, essentially neutralizing the excess hole charge. The time constant for this shielding process  is governed by the dielectric relaxation time of the majority electrons $\tau=\epsilon/\sigma$, where $\sigma  $ is the conductivity of the electrons and   $\epsilon$ the absolute permittivity of the semiconductor.
